# Set different colour for each geom line with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have this data

```
diffdec <- structure(list(ma = structure(c(14975, 14975, 15006, 15006, 15034, 5034, 15065, 15065, 15095, 15095, 15126, 15126, 15156, 15156, 15187, 15187, 15218, 15218, 15248, 15248, 15279, 15279, 15309, 15309, 15340, 15340, 15371, 15371, 15400, 15400, 15431, 15431, 15461, 15461, 15492, 15492, 15522, 15522, 15553, 15553, 15584, 15584, 15614, 15614, 15645, 15645, 15675, 15675, 15706, 15706, 15737, 15737, 15765, 15765, 15796, 15796, 15826, 15826, 15857, 15857, 15887, 15887, 15918, 15918, 15949, 15949, 15979, 15979, 16010, 16010, 16040, 16040, 16071, 16071, 16102, 16102, 16130, 16130, 16161, 16161, 16191, 16191, 16222, 16222, 16252, 16252, 16283, 16283, 16314, 16314, 16344, 16344, 16375, 16375, 16405, 16405, 16436, 16436, 16467, 16467, 16495, 16495, 16526, 16526, 16556, 16556, 16587, 16587, 16617, 16617, 16648, 16648, 16679, 16679, 16709, 16709, 16740, 16740, 16770, 16770, 16801, 16801, 16832, 16832, 16861, 16861, 16892, 16892, 16922, 16922, 16953, 16953, 16983, 16983, 17014, 17014, 17045, 17045, 17075, 17075, 17106, 17106, 17136, 17136, 17167, 17167, 17198, 17198, 17226, 17226, 17257, 17257, 17287, 17287, 17318, 17318, 17348, 17348, 17379, 17379, 17410, 17410, 17440, 17440, 17471, 17471, 17501, 17501, 17532, 17532, 17563, 17563, 17591, 17591, 17622, 17622, 17652, 17652, 17683, 17683, 17713, 17713, 17744, 17744, 17775, 17775, 17805, 17805, 17836, 17836, 17866, 17866, 17897, 17897, 17928, 17928, 17956, 17956, 17987, 17987, 18017, 18017, 18048, 18048, 18078, 18078, 18109, 18109, 18140, 18140, 18170, 18170, 18201, 18201, 18231, 18231, 18262, 18262, 18293, 18293, 18322, 18322, 18353, 18353, 18383, 18383, 18414, 18414, 18444, 18444, 18475, 18475, 18506, 18506, 18536, 18536, 18567, 18567, 18597, 18597, 18628, 18628, 18659, 18659, 18687, 18687, 18718, 18718, 18748, 18748, 18779, 18779, 18809, 18809, 18840, 18840, 18871, 18871, 18901, 18901, 18932, 18932, 18962, 18962), class = "Date"), NOME_REGIONE = c("Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte" ), CLASSE = c("over80", "under80", "over80", "under80", "over80", "under80", "over80", "under80", "over80", "under80", "over80", "under80", "over80", "under80", "over80", "under80", "over80", "under80", "over80", "under80", "over80", "under80", "over80", "under80", "over80", "under80", "over80", "under80", "over80", "under80", "over80", "under80", "over80", "under80", "over80", "under80", "over80", "under80", "over80", "under80", "over80", "under80", "over80", "under80", "over80", "under80", "over80", "under80", "over80", "under80", "over80", "under80", "over80", "under80", "over80", "under80", "over80", "under80", "over80", "under80", "over80", "under80", "over80", "under80", "over80", "under80", "over80", "under80", "over80", "under80", "over80", "under80", "over80", "under80", "over80", "under80", "over80", "under80", "over80", "under80", "over80", "under80", "over80", "under80", "over80", "under80", "over80", "under80", "over80", "under80", "over80", "under80", "over80", "under80", "over80", "under80", "over80", "under80", "over80", "under80", "over80", "under80", "over80", "under80", "over80", "under80", "over80", "under80", "over80", "under80", "over80", "under80", "over80", "under80", "over80", "under80", "over80", "under80", "over80", "under80", "over80", "under80", "over80", "under80", "over80", "under80", "over80", "under80", "over80", "under80", "over80", "under80", "over80", "under80", "over80", "under80", "over80", "under80", "over80", "under80", "over80", "under80", "over80", "under80", "over80", "under80", "over80", "under80", "over80", "under80", "over80", "under80", "over80", "under80", "over80", "under80", "over80", "under80", "over80", "under80", "over80", "under80", "over80", "under80", "over80", "under80", "over80", "under80", "over80", "under80", "over80", "under80", "over80", "under80", "over80", "under80", "over80", "under80", "over80", "under80", "over80", "under80", "over80", "under80", "over80", "under80", "over80", "under80", "over80", "under80", "over80", "under80", "over80", "under80", "over80", "under80", "over80", "under80", "over80", "under80", "over80", "under80", "over80", "under80", "over80", "under80", "over80", "under80", "over80", "under80", "over80", "under80", "over80", "under80", "over80", "under80", "over80", "under80", "over80", "under80", "over80", "under80", "over80", "under80", "over80", "under80", "over80", "under80", "over80", "under80", "over80", "under80", "over80", "under80", "over80", "under80", "over80", "under80", "over80", "under80", "over80", "under80", "over80", "under80", "over80", "under80", "over80", "under80", "over80", "under80", "over80", "under80", "over80", "under80", "over80", "under80", "over80", "under80", "over80", "under80", "over80", "under80", "over80", "under80"), decessi = c(5635, 3755, 5087, 3391, 5396, 3541, 5018, 3442, 4707, 3216, 4464, 3153, 4804, 3238, 4789, 3123, 4358, 2991, 4930, 3276, 5096, 3352, 5384, 3660, 5922, 3842, 5487, 3429, 5585, 3609, 5266, 3382, 4969, 3124, 4875, 2993, 5022, 3178, 4878, 3093, 4628, 2962, 5065, 3262, 5499, 3331, 5602, 3603, 5939, 3729, 5265, 3326, 5734, 3554, 5178, 3186, 4819, 3084, 4718, 2887, 4992, 2998, 4838, 3094, 4636, 2882, 5255, 3290, 5304, 3248, 5682, 3434, 5892, 3586, 5320, 3172, 5698, 3408, 5111, 3223, 4878, 2996, 4737, 2900, 5029, 2966, 4897, 2879, 4718, 2825, 5101, 3135, 5437, 3264, 5632, 3410, 6654, 3841, 5914, 3267, 6353, 3589, 5769, 3326, 5468, 3156, 5279, 2922, 5577, 3168, 5476, 3089, 5168, 2918, 5744, 3236, 5977, 3441, 6289, 3493, 6384, 3570, 5509, 3099, 5890, 3412, 5622, 3066, 5185, 2997, 5002, 2831, 5278, 3053, 5155, 2934, 4881, 2737, 5400, 3124, 5721, 3092, 6245, 3481, 6877, 3745, 5968, 3284, 6312, 3545, 5871, 3118, 5423, 3051, 5450, 2953, 5619, 3046, 5585, 3002, 5174, 2790, 5846, 3203, 5987, 3254, 6438, 3483, 6765, 3623, 5874, 3176, 6434, 3488, 6017, 3126, 5507, 3019, 5398, 2871, 5709, 2977, 5599, 2879, 5199, 2880, 5804, 2986, 6028, 3137, 6406, 3362, 6937, 3442, 5953, 2946, 6454, 3175, 5962, 3036, 5576, 2901, 5439, 2752, 5701, 2881, 5549, 2820, 5299, 2677, 5765, 3050, 5929, 3156, 6632, 3382, 8694, 4100, 7472, 3585, 8246, 3792, 7368, 3605, 7005, 3340, 6827, 3299, 7108, 3420, 7115, 3439, 6680, 3150, 7265, 3494, 7695, 3531, 8055, 3823, 7282, 3711, 6414, 3333, 6686, 3530, 6170, 3237, 5791, 3080, 5641, 3031, 5958, 2995, 5910, 2979, 5473, 2850, 6186, 3298, 6421, 3198, 6630, 3562), deccov = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 702, 579, 1435, 710, 418, 156, 215, 64, 50, 10, 7, 4, 13, 5, 233, 85, 1283, 707, 920, 456, 560, 230, 416, 162, 511, 368, 313, 323, 87, 111, 11, 23, 2, 1, 11, 7, 26, 20, 31, 14, 43, 25, 37, 31), diff = c(5635, 3755, 5087, 3391, 5396, 3541, 5018, 3442, 4707, 3216, 4464, 3153, 4804, 3238, 4789, 3123, 4358, 2991, 4930, 3276, 5096, 3352, 5384, 3660, 5922, 3842, 5487, 3429, 5585, 3609, 5266, 3382, 4969, 3124, 4875, 2993, 5022, 3178, 4878, 3093, 4628, 2962, 5065, 3262, 5499, 3331, 5602, 3603, 5939, 3729, 5265, 3326, 5734, 3554, 5178, 3186, 4819, 3084, 4718, 2887, 4992, 2998, 4838, 3094, 4636, 2882, 5255, 3290, 5304, 3248, 5682, 3434, 5892, 3586, 5320, 3172, 5698, 3408, 5111, 3223, 4878, 2996, 4737, 2900, 5029, 2966, 4897, 2879, 4718, 2825, 5101, 3135, 5437, 3264, 5632, 3410, 6654, 3841, 5914, 3267, 6353, 3589, 5769, 3326, 5468, 3156, 5279, 2922, 5577, 3168, 5476, 3089, 5168, 2918, 5744, 3236, 5977, 3441, 6289, 3493, 6384, 3570, 5509, 3099, 5890, 3412, 5622, 3066, 5185, 2997, 5002, 2831, 5278, 3053, 5155, 2934, 4881, 2737, 5400, 3124, 5721, 3092, 6245, 3481, 6877, 3745, 5968, 3284, 6312, 3545, 5871, 3118, 5423, 3051, 5450, 2953, 5619, 3046, 5585, 3002, 5174, 2790, 5846, 3203, 5987, 3254, 6438, 3483, 6765, 3623, 5874, 3176, 6434, 3488, 6017, 3126, 5507, 3019, 5398, 2871, 5709, 2977, 5599, 2879, 5199, 2880, 5804, 2986, 6028, 3137, 6406, 3362, 6937, 3442, 5953, 2946, 6454, 3175, 5962, 3036, 5576, 2901, 5439, 2752, 5701, 2881, 5549, 2820, 5299, 2677, 5765, 3050, 5929, 3156, 6632, 3382, 8694, 4100, 7470, 3584, 7544, 3213, 5933, 2895, 6587, 3184, 6612, 3235, 7058, 3410, 7108, 3435, 6667, 3145, 7032, 3409, 6412, 2824, 7135, 3367, 6722, 3481, 5998, 3171, 6175, 3162, 5857, 2914, 5704, 2969, 5630, 3008, 5956, 2994, 5899, 2972, 5447, 2830, 6155, 3284, 6378, 3173, 6593, 3531)), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -264L), groups = structure(list( ma = structure(c(14975, 15006, 15034, 15065, 15095, 15126, 15156, 15187, 15218, 15248, 15279, 15309, 15340, 15371, 15400, 15431, 15461, 15492, 15522, 15553, 15584, 15614, 15645, 15675, 15706, 15737, 15765, 15796, 15826, 15857, 15887, 15918, 15949, 15979, 16010, 16040, 16071, 16102, 16130, 16161, 16191, 16222, 16252, 16283, 16314, 16344, 16375, 16405, 16436, 16467, 16495, 16526, 16556, 16587, 16617, 16648, 16679, 16709, 16740, 16770, 16801, 16832, 16861, 16892, 16922, 16953, 16983, 17014, 17045, 17075, 17106, 17136, 17167, 17198, 17226, 17257, 17287, 17318, 17348, 17379, 17410, 17440, 17471, 17501, 17532, 17563, 17591, 17622, 17652, 17683, 17713, 17744, 17775, 17805, 17836, 17866, 17897, 17928, 17956, 17987, 18017, 18048, 18078, 18109, 18140, 18170, 18201, 18231, 18262, 18293, 18322, 18353, 18383, 18414, 18444, 18475, 18506, 18536, 18567, 18597, 18628, 18659, 18687, 18718, 18748, 18779, 18809, 18840, 18871, 18901, 18932, 18962 ), class = "Date"), NOME_REGIONE = c("Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte", "Piemonte" ), .rows = structure(list(1:2, 3:4, 5:6, 7:8, 9:10, 11:12, 13:14, 15:16, 17:18, 19:20, 21:22, 23:24, 25:26, 27:28, 29:30, 31:32, 33:34, 35:36, 37:38, 39:40, 41:42, 43:44, 45:46, 47:48, 49:50, 51:52, 53:54, 55:56, 57:58, 59:60, 61:62, 63:64, 65:66, 67:68, 69:70, 71:72, 73:74, 75:76, 77:78, 79:80, 81:82, 83:84, 85:86, 87:88, 89:90, 91:92, 93:94, 95:96, 97:98, 99:100, 101:102, 103:104, 105:106, 107:108, 109:110, 111:112, 113:114, 115:116, 117:118, 119:120, 121:122, 123:124, 125:126, 127:128, 129:130, 131:132, 133:134, 135:136, 137:138, 139:140, 141:142, 143:144, 145:146, 147:148, 149:150, 151:152, 153:154, 155:156, 157:158, 159:160, 161:162, 163:164, 165:166, 167:168, 169:170, 171:172, 173:174, 175:176, 177:178, 179:180, 181:182, 183:184, 185:186, 187:188, 189:190, 191:192, 193:194, 195:196, 197:198, 199:200, 201:202, 203:204, 205:206, 207:208, 209:210, 211:212, 213:214, 215:216, 217:218, 219:220, 221:222, 223:224, 225:226, 227:228, 229:230, 231:232, 233:234, 235:236, 237:238, 239:240, 241:242, 243:244, 245:246, 247:248, 249:250, 251:252, 253:254, 255:256, 257:258, 259:260, 261:262, 263:264), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame" ), row.names = c(NA, -132L), .drop = TRUE))
```

and used this code to plot them

```
  ggplot(data=diffdec,aes(x=ma,y=decessi,col=CLASSE))+
      geom_line(size=1,lty=2)+
      geom_line(data=diffdec,aes(x=ma,y=diff,col=CLASSE),size=2)+
      geom_line(aes(x=ma,y=deccov, col=CLASSE))+                                  
      xlim(c(my("0111"),my("1221")))+
      theme(legend.position="bottom",
        axis.text = element_text(size = 15),
        axis.title=element_text(size = 20),
        strip.text = element_text(size = 16),
        plot.caption = element_text(size = 20, face = "italic"),
        legend.title = element_text(size = 0),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 15))+
      ylab("Decessi")+
      xlab("Data")
```

[image]

I'd like to show both the dashed lines in a different colour. Is there any way using the above code, or I need to use a different approach?

Comment: By different color, do you mean they still should be two different colors between the groups? Say, yellow and purple dotted lines depending on over/under 80? Or do you want it to be the same “different” color, for instance, gray for both dotted lines?

Comment: The second option you mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

OP clarified that they were looking to change the dotted lines to have the same color, but be different than their respective groups.  In other words, the dashed line for "over80" and for "under80" should both be a different color.  OP did not indicate if the dashed lines should be included in the legend as an entry, but I am assuming that the answer is "yes".

Here's a descriptive example, and OP can extend to their own question, since we don't have any data to work from.

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- iris[which(iris$Species!="versicolor"),]

ggplot(df, aes(Sepal.Length, y=Sepal.Width, col=Species)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_line(aes(y=Petal.Width), lty=2)
```

[image]

Since `color=` is specified globally for the plot via `ggplot(aes(...))`, every geom will by default have the color aesthetic mapped as if `col=Species`.  To override that default, you can refer to the aesthetic inside a particular geom.  In this case, we can color the lines by changing the call to the `geom_line()`.  When `col` is specified there, it overwrites the original mapping.

```
ggplot(df, aes(Sepal.Length, y=Sepal.Width, col=Species)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_line(aes(y=Petal.Width), col="blue", lty=2) +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

To get the line color to appear in the legend, you will need to add the `col=` aesthetic back inside `aes()`, except this time you will want to map to a simple character value (the name of our line).  Doing this effectively "maps" all observations to a new variable where *every value is the same*.  This means all observations are colored the same (what we want), and a legend entry is created.

```
ggplot(df, aes(Sepal.Length, y=Sepal.Width, col=Species)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_line(aes(y=Petal.Width, col="Petals"), lty=2) +
  labs(y="Width") + theme_classic()
```

[image]

Now the line is correct and legend entry is correct, but we didn't specify a color and now the legend entry for "Petals" is a solid line, whereas the line is a dashed line.  One of the best options to fix this is likely to map the `linetype` aesthetic in the same manner as `col` and then use `scale_*_manual()` functions to explicitly define the colors and linetypes:

```
ggplot(df, aes(Sepal.Length, y=Sepal.Width, col=Species, lty=Species)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_line(aes(y=Petal.Width, col="Petals", lty="Petals")) +
  scale_color_manual(
    values = c("setosa" = "red", "virginica" = "blue", "Petals" = "green3")) +
  scale_linetype_manual(
    values = c("setosa" = 1, "virginica" = 1, "Petals" = 2)) +
  labs(y="Width") + theme_classic()
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @chemdork123. I want to get your second plot, so without showing the dashed line on the legend. I got your explanation, but it doesn't seem to work in my case. I edited my post including the data to have a better understanding.

Comment: If you don't want it to show in the legend, just simply add a `color=` aesthetic to the `geom_line()` call that draws the dotted lines.  The second line of your plot code should become: `geom_line(size=1,lty=2, col='gray')`